# What's the SQL query to list all rows that have 2 column sub-rows as duplicates?

Tags: sql, database, platform-agnostic

I have a table that has redundant data and I'm trying to identify all rows that have duplicate sub-rows (for lack of a better word). By sub-rows I mean considering `COL1` and `COL2` only.

So let's say I have something like this:

```
 COL1   COL2   COL3
 ---------------------
 aa     111    blah_x
 aa     111    blah_j
 aa     112    blah_m
 ab     111    blah_s
 bb     112    blah_d
 bb     112    blah_d
 cc     112    blah_w
 cc     113    blah_p
```

I need a SQL query that returns this:

```
 COL1   COL2   COL3
 ---------------------
 aa     111    blah_x
 aa     111    blah_j
 bb     112    blah_d
 bb     112    blah_d
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Does this work for you?

```
select t.* from table t
left join ( select col1, col2, count(*) as count from table group by col1, col2 ) c on t.col1=c.col1 and t.col2=c.col2
where c.count > 1
```

Comment: This is a correct answer.  I think mine will run a hair faster on a large database, but I'd leave that up to a DBA to decide.

Comment: Looks slower than a solution based on an analytic function to me.

Comment: I up-voted this solution but wonder if it would be improved / simpler / faster if (a) the join was not a left join; (b) the sub-query had a "having count(*)>1" clause.  I'm thinking of --

select t.* from tbl t left join 
(select col1,col2 from tbl group by col1,col2 having count(*)>1) c 
on t.col1=c.col1 and t.col2=c.col2

Answer (score 5):

With the data you have listed, your query is not possible.  The data on rows 5 & 6 is not distinct within itself.

Assuming that your table is named 'quux', if you start with something like this:

```
SELECT a.COL1, a.COL2, a.COL3 
FROM quux a, quux b
WHERE a.COL1 = b.COL1 AND a.COL2 = b.COL2 AND a.COL3 <> b.COL3
ORDER BY a.COL1, a.COL2
```

You'll end up with this answer:

```
 COL1   COL2   COL3
 ---------------------
 aa     111    blah_x
 aa     111    blah_j
```

That's because rows 5 & 6 have the same values for COL3.  Any query that returns both rows 5 & 6 will also return duplicates of ALL of the rows in this dataset.

On the other hand, if you have a primary key (ID), then you can use this query instead:

```
SELECT a.COL1, a.COL2, a.COL3
FROM quux a, quux b
WHERE a.COL1 = b.COL1 AND a.COL2 = b.COL2 AND a.ID <> b.ID
ORDER BY a.COL1, a.COL2
```

*[Edited to simplify the WHERE clause]*

And you'll get the results you want:

```
COL1   COL2   COL3
---------------------
aa     111    blah_x
aa     111    blah_j
bb     112    blah_d
bb     112    blah_d
```

I just tested this on SQL Server 2000, but you should see the same results on any modern SQL database.

**[blorgbeard](https://stackoverflow.com/users/369/blorgbeard) proved me [wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/131014/whats-the-sql-query-to-list-all-rows-that-have-2-column-sub-rows-as-duplicates#131036) -- good for him!**

Answer (score 4):

Join on yourself like this:

```
SELECT a.col3, b.col3, a.col1, a.col2 
FROM tablename a, tablename b
WHERE a.col1 = b.col1 AND a.col2 = b.col2 AND a.col3 != b.col3
```

If you're using postgresql, you can use the oid to make it return less duplicated results, like this:

```
SELECT a.col3, b.col3, a.col1, a.col2 
FROM tablename a, tablename b
WHERE a.col1 = b.col1 AND a.col2 = b.col2 AND a.col3 != b.col3
  AND a.oid < b.oid
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't have a database handy to test this, but I think it should work...

```
select
  *
from
  theTable
where
  col1 in
    (
    select
      col1
    from
      theTable
    group by
      col1||col2
    having
      count(col1||col2) > 1
    )
```

Comment: This fails on SQL Server because 'col1' isn't present in the GROUP BY clause.  I'm pretty sure this will fail on most other SQL databases.

Answer (score 2):

My naive attempt would be

```
select a.*, b.* from table a, table b where a.col1 = b.col1 and a.col2 = b.col2 and a.col3 != b.col3;
```

but that would return all the rows twice.  I'm not sure how you'd restrict it to just returning them once.  Maybe if there was a primary key, you could add "and a.pkey < b.pkey".

Like I said, that's not elegant and there is probably a better way to to do this.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should work:

```
SELECT a.COL1, a.COL2, a.COL3
FROM YourTable a
JOIN YourTable b ON b.COL1 = a.COL1 AND b.COL2 = a.COL2 AND b.COL3 <> a.COL3
```

In general, the JOIN clause should include every column that you're considering to be part of a "duplicate" (COL1 and COL2 in this case), and at least one column (or as many as it takes) to eliminate a row joining to itself (COL3, in this case).

Answer (score 2):

This is pretty similar to the self-join, except it will not have the duplicates.

```
select COL1,COL2,COL3
from theTable a
where exists (select 'x'
              from theTable b
              where a.col1=b.col1
              and   a.col2=b.col2
              and   a.col3<>b.col3)
order by col1,col2,col3
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you find duplicates.   Tested in oracle 10g with your data.

select * from tst
where (col1, col2) in 
(select col1, col2 from tst group by col1, col2 having count(*) > 1)

Answer (score 0):

select COL1,COL2,COL3

from table

group by COL1,COL2,COL3

having count(*)>1

Comment: This does not work.  Examine the blah_x row in the question to understand why.

Answer (score 0):

Forget joins -- use an analytic function:

```
select col1, col2, col3
from
(
select col1, col2, col3, count(*) over (partition by col1, col2) rows_per_col1_col2
from table
)
where rows_per_col1_col2 > 1
```

Comment: That only works if your database supports it.  SQL Server 2005 does, and presumably Oracle does.  SQL Server 2000 does not, nor does MySQL or PostgresQL.

Comment: Ah, something new to learn.  Should there be another from clause in this?